# Copy text from textbox onto the clipboard within an already set clipboard button using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to have input from a textbox be set within a copy and paste button. Basically I want someone to be able to type their initials in the textbox and then have those initials be inputted within the clipboard within an already settext.

```
  private void AvayaNewInstall(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("These FSR notes are to be 
   used when there is no history of" +
            "EnergyWise ever being installed at the premise previously.");

        Clipboard.SetText(@"NEW INSTALL EW ON: 

 EMAIL REQUEST FROM: NAME 

 WIFI AVAILABILITY:

 AH LOCATION:

 WH LOCATION:

 BEST CONTACT NUMBER:

 Initials");
    }
```

where it says initials I want the texbox input to be there.

```
 Clipboard.SetText(initials.Text);
```

I am confused as to where I would put that. If I put it in between the quotations it just comes out as what I put in and not what it is in the textbox.

Comment: concat strings : `Clipboard.SetText(@" tl;dr " + initials.Text);`

Comment: Thanks! it worked!